# Switch between JSON array options on click

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to switch between the array options when clicking a button by changing the value of a variable. I cannot get it to work. Perhaps this isn't the best way to do it? I'm still learning this and I'm struggling to spot the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help

```js
var json = {
  "content": [{
      "title": "Test 1",
    },
    {
      "title": "Test 2",
    }
  ]
};

var output = ""; //initialize it outside the loop
var maxAppend = 0;

var foo = json.content[0];

function first() {
  foo = json.content[0];
}

function second() {
  foo = json.content[1];
}

$.each(json.content[0], function() {
  if (maxAppend >= 1) return;

  output += '<h2>' + foo.title + '</h2>' +
    '<div><button onclick="second()">click</button></div>'

  maxAppend++;

});

$('.container').append(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/u63ggmzf/)

Comment: Questions should be self-contained so they don't rely on external links.  It's okay to add links but they should never be required in order for the question to make sense (links can break).  I've added the code to the question for you.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks @Archer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written your code that will work just for once and `click` event does not update the text as it has been put in the DOM. Because you have a variable `foo` and it has the reference to the object.

Yet you need to talk to the DOM to update it's text content. One way i have mentioned. Although you might want to go unobtrusive.

You have to pass `this` to the function:

```
onclick="second(this)"
```

Now in the function:

```
function second(el){
  $(el).parent().prev('h2').text(json.content[1]['title']);
}
```

You might add a event listener for your dynamic button in jquery with delegated event:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'button' second);
function second(){
    $(this).parent().prev('h2').text(json.content[1]['title']);
}
```

```js
var json = {
  "content": [{"title": "Test 1",},{"title": "Test 2",}]
};
var output = ""; //initialize it outside the loop
var maxAppend = 0;
var foo = json.content[0];

function first() {
  foo = json.content[0];
}
function second(el) {
  $(el).parent().prev('h2').text(json.content[1]['title']);
}

$.each(json.content, function() {
    output += '<h2>' + foo.title + '</h2>' +
    '<div><button onclick="second(this)">click</button></div>'
  maxAppend++;
});

$('.container').append(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: While this would work I think it might be good to explain that they're not getting the expected result with their code as they're just updating the JS variable and not updating the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Jai. The actual JSON I'm working with has 11 objects in each option. Is it ok to fill the function with 11 changes?

Comment: just updated the added snippet take a look if you need something like this.

Comment: @Jai Thanks for your help! Your answer has lead me to a success. I've marked it as Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure about what you want to do.

here is an example i make for handle switch value

[click here to watch](https://jsfiddle.net/zq12eLyy/1/)

```
var Json = {
  "content": [{
    "title": "Test 1",
},
{
    "title": "Test 2",
 }]
 };

 var select = 0;
  var text = $("#text");

  var handleSwitch = function(){
  if (select === 0){
    $(text).html(Json.content[1].title);
    select = 1;
  }else if(select === 1){
     $(text).html(Json.content[0].title);
     select = 0;
  }
 }

 $('#button').on("click", function(event){
    handleSwitch();
 });

<div class="container">
  <button id="button">click</button>
  <p id="text">Test 1</p>
</div>
```